# SharePoint 2010 - Change Password WebPart?

Tags: web-part, active-directory, user-accounts

I´m searching for a free SharePoint 2010 WebPart to change the password from the current user.

Comment: Please specify what authentication method(s) you are using...lots of free FBA stuff out there, not so much for AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any free 2010 web parts for AD...lots for fee.

I've used this one in 2007, but not in 2010: http://changepassword.codeplex.com.  The following discussion thread seems to indicate success implementing it with 2010: http://changepassword.codeplex.com/discussions/219795